# Filtering an array of objects by an object where all fields of the object values are respected

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this:

```
let object = {
  name: "john",
  lastName: 'doe'
}

let arrayOfObjects = [
 {
  name: 'john',
  lastName: 'fake'
 },
 {
  name: 'josh',
  lastName: 'doe'
 },
 {
  name: 'john',
  lastName: 'doe',
 }
]
```

This is my code:

```
 let filteredNames = []
     arrayOfObjects.filter((map)=> {
      Object.keys(object).map(key=> {
        if(map[key].toLowerCase() === filters[key].toLowerCase()) {
          // console.log(map)
          filteredNames.push(map)
        }
      })
  })
```

Yet this returns all of them because at least one of the keys are respeted but **not all of the keys**
How can I modify to fix this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of `.filter()` and `.every()` should do the trick for you:

```js
let object = {
  name: "John",
  lastName: 'doe'
}

let arrayOfObjects = [
 {
  name: 'john',
  lastName: 'fake'
 },
 {
  name: 'josh',
  lastName: 'doe'
 },
 {
  name: 'john',
  lastName: 'Doe',
 }
];

const res=arrayOfObjects.filter(o=>Object.entries(object).every(([k,v])=>v.toLowerCase()==o[k].toLowerCase()));
console.log(res);

// Nina suggested quite rightly to prepare an "entries" array
// *before* the filtering starts. With very large arrayOfObjects this can be a little faster:

const entries=Object.entries(object).map(([k,v])=>[k,v.toLowerCase()]);
const resN=arrayOfObjects.filter(o=>entries.every(([k,v])=>v==o[k].toLowerCase()));
console.log(resN);
```

I now also added the `.toLowerCase()` conversion to make the filtering case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you require you can use `Object.values()` to create an array of all the values you want to find in the object, and then `Array.filter()` and `Array.every()` to retrieve the object matching *both* of those values:

```js
let filters = { name: "john", lastName: 'doe' }
let arrayOfObjects = [{ name: 'john', lastName: 'fake' }, { name: 'josh', lastName: 'doe' }, { name: 'john', lastName: 'doe' }]

let filterValues = Object.values(filters);
let filteredNames = arrayOfObjects.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).every(v => filterValues.includes(v)));

console.log(filteredNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get the entries first, because of having this entrie not build all time of iterating and then filter by looking at all entries.

```js
const
    object = { name: "john", lastName: 'doe' },
    arrayOfObjects = [{ name: 'john', lastName: 'fake' }, { name: 'josh', lastName: 'doe' }, { name: 'john', lastName: 'doe' }],
    entries = Object.entries(object),
    result = arrayOfObjects.filter(o => entries.every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v));

console.log(result);
```